# matplotlib application issue by python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to show a picture but I want to hide the window frame.

I tryed the code `frameon=False` in `plt.figure()` but the window frame is still there. Just the background color turns to grey.

The target is to show the picture only, without any matplotlib interface.

Is it feasible?

The point is that I didn't want to save a picture file without frame or axis.
But I want to show the picture on the screen which without the frame or toolbar or the window.

Here is the code and running result.
The picture was showing with the window even I add the "frameon=False" in the code.

[image: Link for issue screenshot]

Comment: can you explain this a little more, give a minimal working example with the current result and the wanted result?

Comment: Yes. I want to show a QR image on the screen only without any window element (like the software toolbar, etc.). So to show a picture independently is the purpose.